# Should I just use a single table?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have an entity `Order`.

The order has information on date, client, associate who handled order etc.

Now the order also needs to store a state i.e. differentiate between won orders and lost orders.

The idea is that a customer may submit an order to the company, but could eventually *back out*.

(As domain info, the order is not of items. It is a services company that tries to handle clients and makes offers on when they can deliver an order and at what price etc. So the customer may find a better burgain and back up and stop the ordering process from the company).

The company wants data on both won orders and lost orders and the difference between a won order and a lost order is just a couple of more attributes e.g. `ReasonLost` which could be `Price` or `Time`.

My question is, what would be the best representation of the `Order`?

I was thinking of using a single table and just have for the orders won, the `ReasonLost` as null.

Does it make sense to create separate tables for `WonOrder` and `LostOrder` if the difference of these new entities is not significant?

What would be the best model for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one table.  Add an OrderState Field.

Caveat:  If you are doing millions of transactions per day, then decisions like this need much more attention and analysis.

Comment: Ok. But how would it defer depending on the ammount of transactions per day? Even in this case, a single table would be faster, i.e. no `JOIN`.Unless I am misunderstanding the `Caveat` part of you answer

Comment: The larger the system, the more careful we must tread.  Retrieving single table data is faster than joining, but with large systems, conserving diskspace can also be an issue, reporting/datamining can be an issue, table security can be an issue, etc., etc., etc.  Caveat on the Caveat: In general, I've seen more problems caused by over-engineering than under-engineering.

Answer (score 1):

There is another alternative design that you might consider.  In this alternative you keep a second table for the order lost reason and relate it to your order table as an optional 1:1.  Note that this is effectively an implementation of a supertype/subtype pattern where the lost order subtype has one additional attribute.

It looks like this:

[image: ERD]

This alternative might be attractive under any of the following circumstances:

- You lose very few orders.
- Your order table isn't wide enough to hold a long enough lost order reason.
- Your lost order reason is very, very big (even BLOB).
- You have an aesthetic objection to maintaining a lost order reason in your order table.